# Change font colour based on variable number value

Tags: javascript, colors

```html
<main>

<div class=counter-container>
    <h1 class="counter-value">(..)</h1>
      <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="btn-add">+</button>
        <button class="btn-minus">-</button>
        <button class="btn-reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
</div>
</main>
<script src="counter.js"></script>
```

I'm pretty new to JavaScript. Today I started a mini project to help the lessons sink in. I’ve managed to successfully build a counter but I’m having trouble changing the font colour based on the counter value. I’m trying to change the font colour as follows: orange = 0, red <= -1, green => 1. I’m staring at this code and I can’t work out what I’m doing wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is my current code:

```js
// counter 
let count = 0;

let btndisplay = document.querySelector('.counter-value');
let btnadd = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
let btnminus = document.querySelector('.btn-minus');
let btnreset = document.querySelector('.btn-reset');


btnadd.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count++;
    updateDisplay();
}) ;

btnminus.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count--;
    updateDisplay()
}) ;

function updateDisplay(){
    btndisplay.innerHTML = count;
};

btnreset.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count = 0;
    updateDisplay()
}) ;


updateDisplay();

// change colour of font based on counter value 

function changeColor() {

  if(count >= 0){
    btndisplay.style.color = 'green';
  } else if (count == 0){
    btndisplay.style.color = 'orange';
  } else if (count <= -1){
    btndisplay.style.color = 'red';
  }

};

changeColor();
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS (if you have any)?

Comment: Sure thing. I've added the html.

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli answered correctly below. You need to call `changeColor()` everytime `updateDisplay()` is called. Put the `changeColor()` call inside that function.

Answer (score 1):

You only call the `changeColor` once at start.

You need to call it after every change, so include it in `updateDisplay`.

(additionally you need to change the first `if` in your check, because it is `if(count >= 0)` when it should be `if(count >= 1)`

```js
// counter 
let count = 0;

let btndisplay = document.querySelector('.counter-value');
let btnadd = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
let btnminus = document.querySelector('.btn-minus');
let btnreset = document.querySelector('.btn-reset');


btnadd.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count++;
    updateDisplay();
}) ;

btnminus.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    count--;
    updateDisplay()
}) ;

function updateDisplay(){
    btndisplay.innerHTML = count; 
    changeColor();
};

btnreset.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count = 0;
    updateDisplay()
}) ;


updateDisplay();

// change colour of font based on counter value 

function changeColor() {

  if(count >= 1){
    btndisplay.style.color = 'green';
  } else if (count == 0){
    btndisplay.style.color = 'orange';
  } else if (count <= -1){
    btndisplay.style.color = 'red';
  }

};
```

```html
<div class="counter-value"></div>
<button class="btn-add">add</button>
<button class="btn-minus">minus</button>
<button class="btn-reset">reset</button>
```